# Flask Blueprint not working

Tags: flask

I have a strange situation and have no idea how to find the problem.

I have created a blueprint like this

```
reportjobsmod = Blueprint('jobreports', __name__, url_prefix='/jobreports', template_folder='templates')
```

And I have created routes like the following in the `views.py` file

```
@reportjobsmod.route('/crc_booksdue/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def crc_booksdue():
```

Then I use

```
action="{{ url_for('jobreports.crc_booksdue') }}"
```

in the template.

This all works fine with a couple more routes.

However, when I try to add the following route to my views.py

```
@reportjobsmod.route('/job_status/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def jobs_status():
```

and enter

```
action="{{ url_for('jobreports.job_status') }}"
```

in the template I get routing.BuildError

I tried changing the name of the route, I replaced it with an existing route (which worked ok in the template)

I printed out app.url_map and the jobreports.job_status is there along with the other routes.

What do I try next?

Comment: When you use `url_for` make sure you use the name of the function. In your case it should be `url_for('jobreports.jobs_status')` and not `url_for('jobreports.job_status)`

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem. If I change the name of the function to be exactly the same as the route it works, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) documentation:

> Generates a URL to the given endpoint with the method provided.

That's the *method* from your app, as spelled in the app.

Your error is from

> The url_for function results in a BuildError when the current app does not have a URL for the given endpoint and values.

The `endpoint` parameter for the function states

> endpoint – the endpoint of the URL (name of the function)

In the [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building), there's also a mention:

> To build a URL to a specific function you can use the url_for() function. It accepts the name of the function as first argument [...]